# Saving a bitmap of OpenTK screen, but the QuickFont text doesn't show up?

Tags: c#, opengl, opentk

I've got a textured box in my window. On top of this box text prints using QuickFont. Since there is a lot of text being added and not all at once, it consumes time to refresh this screen. To save time and resources I want to screencap the box with text and use it as a texture which is much faster because there's nothing to parse out after the first render.

I can get the glControl to screen cap itself and save it to a bitmap but there's no text on the screen. (F.Y.I this is supposed to be a WYSIWYG render of a printout for pharmacy labels)

***Is there a way to get the text to save as well?***

```
            if (GraphicsContext.CurrentContext == null)
            throw new GraphicsContextException();

        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(frm1.ClientSize.Width, frm1.ClientSize.Height);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData data =
            bmp.LockBits(frm1.ClientRectangle, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.WriteOnly,
            System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        GL.ReadPixels(0, 0, frm1.ClientSize.Width,frm1.ClientSize.Height,
            OpenTK.Graphics.OpenGL.PixelFormat.Bgr, PixelType.UnsignedByte, data.Scan0);
        bmp.UnlockBits(data);

        bmp.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.RotateNoneFlipY);
        bmp.Save("Move.bmp", ImageFormat.Bmp);
        bmp.Dispose();
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally stumbled upon the answer. By clicking the button that grabs the screen cap twice the second one displayed the correct information including the text.

Even though the call to the screenshot happens after the text is "supposedly" rendered and the buffers have been swapped, it still is grabbing the screen shot from what is on the screen at the moment the OnClick event is fired.

The solution I will look into is just making a Boolean (finished) and setting it to true at the end of the text render segment and having a

`while (Finished = true){ Do bitmap stuff here }`

Or alternatively have a counter variable that counts up for each line of text parsed and when it reaches the maximum (I.E. everything has been rendered) it calls the grab screenshot method.)